# help with a gold sparkling shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I need some help with a shader I'm trying to make. I made renderings of darts (don't ask me why) and I'm trying to find a way to make a shader to look like the [grip of this dart](http://s1192.photobucket.com/user/crimdart/media/dartsreviews/wrighteuro1120g/10wrighteurodi20g7_zpsrvetqxd4.jpg.html):

[image]

I tried a way of adding noise and the such (like making it look like glitter), but the speckles are fairly small, and it doesn't even remotely look like this.

I'm using cycles render, any idea on how to do this? Keep in mind I'm not super experienced, so if the solution is a fairly complex one, some screenshots or a step by step would be helpful.

To help you, understand the grip is supposed to have small diamonds in it, thats why it is so sparkly.

thank you for any help you provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a more PBR based set up, but since you mentioned you are fairly new to Blender I don't want to get to involved with the node set up.

A simple node set up could look like this. (It's not exactly right but maybe it is close enough for you. If I have more time I will try to do a more advanced shader)
[image]

To get those sparkles to really shine you may need to do some post processing. Although they show up a little better when you move the camera around.

I am just mixing between glossy shaders with a noise texture in the displacement to get that grainy texture.

Try messing the with value of the multiply node to get the shine that you want.

Also maybe darken the tan glossy shader some more, so the white sparkles pop better.

W/O displacement: 
[image]

Comment: Displacement isn't doing anything in this setup, It's better to just use it as Bump Map connected to Normal slots in Fresnel, Diffuse and Glossy.

Comment: Sure it is (although subtle). I attached am image with disp turned to zero. I was going to do normal maps but didnt want to have too many nodes for someone who is new to blender.

Comment: Did you use microdisplacement for this?

Comment: No I did not, and I agree with you though normals would be better. I was just trying to think of the simplest and quickest way.

Comment: Well ok then, I didn't used displacement before microdisplacement shows in Experimental Features but somewhere in my mind was statement that it's doing nothing :) My honest mistake :)

Comment: You are correct in your thinking though. From what I understood it didn't do much of anything before microdisplacement but it was fixed to work as it should even if you don't use microdisplacement. So its a fairly new fix from what I gather.

Comment: this is actually almost exactly what i was looking for.im not new to blender,just new to more advanced shaders,since i was doing mostly modeling.

i dont really like useing displacement,and normal maps since my computer is fairly slow,and displacement maps dont really help on that end :). I will try what you posted,and i will get back to you for more help if needed.

thank you for taking the time to build and post this!

PS:what basic postprocessing options would i have to get this to look even better than it allready is?

Comment: Adding a glare node in the compositor can help. Not sure what you use for post processing.  Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped ;) thx

Comment: allrighty done!again thank you very much for your help,and for showing me some stuff,that will definetely be helpful to me in the future!take care!