# Another holographic hot stamping material

Tags: texturing, materials

[holographic hot stamping on packaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqjpj.jpg)

[image: 1st setup]

[image: 2nd setup]

Hi, How do I get the holographic hot stamping effect like this?
[image]
I've tried few setup but non of them look a like.
Please help....

Comment: Or [Adding mix shaders and glossy shaders](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40445/adding-mix-shaders-and-glossy-shaders) or [How to create a glitter textuer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45358/how-to-create-a-glitter-texture) or [gold sparkling shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79885/help-with-a-gold-sparkling-shader)